# Jquery Ajax PUT request to send a file on backend

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, put

Hi I need to send a file to my backend from browser with PUT. I have a input type file  where I select the file and then try to send it via jquery ajax.

Basically What I need to do is to simulate this request witch is passed as an example in my REST interface documentation.

```
PUT http://localhost:8099/upload
Content-Type: application/binary
Filename: C:\ProgramData\ualdscert.der
```

This is my javascript so far... but still not working. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
 $("#fileUpload").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "/upload",
            type: "PUT",
            data: { Filename : $("#fileUpload").val()},
            processData : false,
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(responseData){
               alert(""succes");
            }
        }); 
});
```

Comment: You aren't actually uploading a file - you are just `PUT`-ing the filename. You need to read the file data and send it along as part of your request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously